# What makes this work?

Tags: php

I am trying to use this chunk of code as template, but Im not fully understanding of how one line works. I'll first provide the full chunk, then I'll single out the line I don't understand.

```
/** settings **/
$images_dir = 'preload-images/';
$thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-thumbs/';
$thumbs_width = 200;
$images_per_row = 3;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
$index = 0;
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
    $index++;
    $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
        $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
        if($extension) {
            make_thumb($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width);
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
    if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
}
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}
```

I understand how everything with the exception of this line works.

```
if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
```

I know it is getting its value from this line:

```
$images_per_row = 3;
```

But what actually makes this work? Im still pretty new to php, and I would like a better understanding of the code Im about to use before I use it.

Any answers at all would be appreciative!

Comment: http://alvinalexander.com/php/php-modulus-operator-syntax-examples  do you understand modulus operator ?

Comment: So what Im getting from the example you posted is its checking if there is a remainder left over? @FastSnail

Comment: The objective of the code was to put a clear fix div (separator) after each row, since each row has three items then $index % 3 when == 0 put that div. But you should know how modulo operator works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$index % $images_per_row == 0
```

The % means "mod", example 4 mod 2 = 0.

A % B = the remainder when we divide A by B.

In your script, the condition is met (valued to 'true') when the remainder of `$index` divided by `$images_per_row` equals 0, meaning the divisibility of  `$index` by `$images_per_row`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Between your answer and the example in the link provided by Fast Snail I am now understanding how it works. I have never used a modulo before (at least not in my own custom code), so when I saw this I was confused. Since 3 / 3 leaves no remainder, it runs my code. Thanks for your answer and your help!

Comment: Glad to help. If you are new to PHP then I recommend you read about operators. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp is a good starter tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the *modulo operator*. It divides the two numbers and then returns the remainder after the division.

It is quite easy to understand if you remember your fractions and how to reduce them to their lowest terms.

So, if we make `5 % 2` into a fraction and reduce it:

```
 5       1  (this is the remainder)
--- → 2 ---
 2       2
```

So, `5 % 2 = 1`.

If we take `8 % 3` we can do the same thing:

```
 8       2 (this is the remainder)
--- → 2 ---
 3       3
```

So, `8 % 3 = 2`.

If there is no remainder, such as in `9 % 3` then you will get `0` back. See:

```
 9       0 (this is the remainder)
--- → 3 ---
 3       3
```

You can write some PHP to see what the values are when doing the modulo operations:

```
$perRow = 3;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "$i % $perRow = ", $i % $perRow, ' | ', "$i / $perRow = ", ($i / $perRow), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 % 3 = 0 | 0 / 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1 | 1 / 3 = 0.33333333333333
2 % 3 = 2 | 2 / 3 = 0.66666666666667
3 % 3 = 0 | 3 / 3 = 1
4 % 3 = 1 | 4 / 3 = 1.3333333333333
5 % 3 = 2 | 5 / 3 = 1.6666666666667
6 % 3 = 0 | 6 / 3 = 2
7 % 3 = 1 | 7 / 3 = 2.3333333333333
8 % 3 = 2 | 8 / 3 = 2.6666666666667
9 % 3 = 0 | 9 / 3 = 3
```